# Double integral over $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to compute $$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} (x^2+y^2+1)^{\frac{-3}{2}} \, dx dy$$

I know that it's a sensible idea to use polar coordinates here and so I want to look at $$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} (r^2+1)^{\frac{-3}{2}} r  \, dr d\theta$$

What would be my upper limit for $r$ though? Would it be $\infty?$

Comment: Since you are integrating over the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$, I guess the upper limit should indeed be $\infty$.

Comment: Yes, the limit would be $\infty$ since you are integrating over the entire plane.

Comment: Notice, however, that your function is undefined on and inside the unit circle.

Comment: @sksks52 What is the problem with the calculation of the integral ? $-\left(r^2+1\right)^{-1/2}$ is an anti-derivative of $r\left(r^2+1\right)^{-3/2}$, so one can formally integrates.

Comment: @Nicolas I have done that now. Should the answer be $2 \pi$?

Comment: @sksks52 Yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}(x^2+y^2+1)^{-3/2}\,dx\,dy = 2\pi\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\rho\,d\rho}{(\rho^2+1)^{3/2}} = \pi\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{(1+u)^{3/2}}=\color{red}{2\pi}. $$

Answer (score 0):

With the coordinate transformation $(r,\phi) \rightarrow (r \, \sin \phi, r \, \cos \phi)$ you map $[0,\infty) \times [0,2\pi)$ to $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ so the boundaries in the second formula would be

$$\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \int_0^\infty dr \ldots$$

As mentioned the the comment your function is not bounded on the unit circle ([If a function $f(x)$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, is $f(x)$ bounded on $[a,b]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610054/if-a-function-fx-is-riemann-integrable-on-a-b-is-fx-bounded-on-a)).