# When stating the properties of integrals, why do we require their respective functions to be bounded in addition to being integrable?

Tags: calculus, integration, definition

When I learned about the properties of integrals, as the one below, for instance, I noticed the preamble of the theorem requires the respective functions to be both bounded and integrable.

> If $f$ and $g$ are bounded, integrable functions on $[a, b]$, then so is $f + g$ and
>
> $$ \int_a^b (f(x) + g(x)) dx = \int_a^b f(x) dx + \int_a^b g(x) dx $$

My question is why do the functions have to be bounded? Isn't it enough for them to be integrable? I have not completed my Calculus course yet, so there are certain concepts I don't know about yet, like improper integrals.

Comment: If the function is integrable on $[a,b]$ then it must also be bounded by definition. See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610054/if-a-function-fx-is-riemann-integrable-on-a-b-is-fx-bounded-on-a) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous comment is correct: integrable functions are bounded by definition. I think the reason that the word "bounded" is emphasized here does indeed have to do with improper integrals. For example, if $\int^{b}_{a} f(x) dx$ converges to $+ \infty$ and $\int^{b}_{a} g(x) dx$ converges to $- \infty$, then their sum is equal to $\infty - \infty$, which is an indeterminate form.

Comment: What would $\int_a^b [f(x) + g(x)]\, dx$ evaluate to in the example you gave? Would it evaluate to $0$?