# Are Riemann integrable functions on a closed and bounded interval continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, riemann-integration, monotone-functions

I know continuous function and monotone functions are Riemann integrable, but I’m not sure if Riemann integrable functions are continuous?

Comment: Continuous and monotone functions are Riemann integrable only if they are **bounded**, otherwise they need not be. For example, $\tan x$ in $[0,\pi/2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. A bounded function $f\colon[a,b]\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ is Riemann-integrable if and only if it is continuous almost everywhere. But not necessarily everywhere; take for instance$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&[a,b]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x=a\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$

Comment: Or with more discontinuities: $f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1n&\text{id }x=\frac kn, \gcd(k,n)=1\\0&\text{if }x\notin\Bbb Q\end{cases}$

Comment: If and only if continuous almost everywhere **and bounded**.

Comment: @user658409 Since I wrote that $f$ is bounded, I don't understand your remark.

Answer (score 5):

No, try to show that the function (which is clearly not continuous) $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0,& x \neq 0,\\ 1,& x=1 \end{cases} $$ is Riemann integrable on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: So can we say that Riemann intégrable function is continuous almost everywhere?

Comment: Yes, that is true. It is called the Lebesgue Criterion for Riemann Integration.

Comment: Well continuous almost everywhere **and bounded**

Comment: @user658409 I would kindly ask you to reread the comments above before hitting capslock... I was asked whether Riemann integrable implies continuous almost everywhere. I was not asked whether it is equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

As others have already pointed out, a Riemann integrable function needn't be continuous. Yet, there is another result which is really useful : any Riemann integrable function is bounded (see here for more details [If a function $f(x)$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, is $f(x)$ bounded on $[a,b]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610054/if-a-function-fx-is-riemann-integrable-on-a-b-is-fx-bounded-on-a)).
The converse is not true, just take $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = \begin{cases} 0,& x \in \mathbb{Q},\\ 1,& x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$ (a classic application of the Lebesgue Criterion you weere told about).

Answer (score 1):

No, not at all. Here is the precise relation of continuity and Riemann-integrability:

> Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function.
>
> Then $f$ is Riemann-integrable if and only if the set of points at
>   which $f$ is discontinuous has Lebesgue-measure $0$.

In particular, since countable sets have measure zero, any function that is discontinuous on a countable set and continuous elsewhere will be Riemann-integrable.

So for example the function

$$ \operatorname{sgn}(x): [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$$

will be Riemann-integrable, but this is not continuous at $0$.