# Why the primitive of a Riemann functions must be continuous?

Tags: integration, analysis, continuity, riemann-integration

Intuitively why must the primitive $F$ of a function $f$ that is Riemann integrable in $[a,b]$, be continuous in $[a,b]$?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429769/is-an-integral-always-continuous

Comment: No , my question is what may happens is the primitive F is continuous in [a,b] and we assure that f is Riemann integrable

Comment: Because f is bounded hence F is Lipschitz.

Comment: I think the answer to this question may depend on what one put into the word "primitive function". What is your definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ then there is an $M$ with $|f(t)|\leq M$ for all $t\in[a,b]$. Now let $F$ be a primitive of $f$ on $[a,b]$, for example $$F(x):=\int_a^x f(t)\>dt\qquad(a\leq x\leq b)\ .$$
Then for arbitrary $a\leq x<y\leq b$ one has
$$F(y)-F(x)=\int_x^y f(t)\>dt\ ,$$
and therefore
$$\bigl|F(y)-F(x)\bigr|\leq \int_x^y \bigl|f(t)\bigr|\>dt\leq M|y-x|\ .$$
This implies that $F$ is $M$-Lipschitz continuous on $[a,b]$.

Comment: What justify the existence of $M$ upper bound of $|f|$

Comment: I mean why is $|f| $ bounded?

Comment: @GuyFabrice: This is a basic requirement of Riemann integrability under any definition. When $f$ is unbounded then the set of possible Riemann sums will always be unbounded, however fine the chosen partition.

Comment: Yes your right but I am wondering why that fact does not apply to the function $x\mapsto |x|^{-a}$ with $0<a<1$ which is Riemann integrable on $(-1,1)$ but bounded.

Comment: @GuyFabrice: This function is not Riemann integrable over $[-1,1]$, but the improper Riemann integral $\lim_{\epsilon\to0+}\int_{[-1,-\epsilon]\cup[\epsilon,1]}\ldots$ exists.