# Cauchy-Peano existence result for the integro-differential equation $u' = f(t,u) = \int_0^t k(u(s)) \text{d}s$ for $k \in C_b(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, continuity, integral-equations

I have an ODE
$$u' = f(t,u) = \int_0^t k(u(s)) \text{ d}s$$ with an initial data $u_0$. Here, $k \in C_b(\mathbb{R})$ is a continuous and bounded function such that $|k(x)| \leq C$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

I want to apply the Cauchy-Peano theorem to this ODE to show that there exists a $C^1$ solution $u$.

Let $u$ be fix. Then $t \mapsto f(t,u)$ is continuous, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429769/is-an-integral-always-continuous).

Let $t$ be fix. And let $u_n(x) \to u(x)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (almost every $x$ would be enough). Then, since $k$ is continuous and bounded, we also have $k(u_n(x)) \to k(u(x))$ for almost every $x$ and $|k(u_n(x))| \leq C$. Therefore, by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, we have

$$f(t,u_n)=\int_0^t k(u_n(s)) \text{ d}s \longrightarrow \int_0^t k(u(s)) \text{ d}s=f(t,u),$$

and $u \mapsto f(t,u)$ is continuous for fixed $t$.

Therefore, Cauchy-Peano gives me the existence of a $C^1$ solution to the above ODE.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument does not give you the existence of a solution, only that if an approximating and converging sequence exists then the limit satisfies (parts of) the original equation.

---

But you can easily transform your equation into an ordinary ODE by differentiating once more,
$$
u''=k(u), ~~ u(0)=u_0,~ u'(0)=0.
$$
To that or its first order version
$$
u'=v\\
v'=k(u)
$$
you can now apply the usual Peano theorem and conclude the existence of local solutions.

Comment: Was my continuity argument incorrect? And if I take two functions $u$, $v$, then
$$|f(t,u)-f(t,v)| \leq \int_0^t |k(u(s))-k(v(s))| ds \leq L t \|u-v\|_\infty,$$
if I assume $k$ to be Lipschitz continuous. Does this work? Thank you for the alternative argument.

Comment: What is the argument $u$ in $f(t,u)$? In your calculation it is a point in a function space. You are thus far outside the usual frame for the Cauchy-Peano theorem, where $f$ is a function of time and a finite dimensional state vector.

Comment: Do you think that it would make more sense if I look at $u'=f(t,u)=\int_0^t k(s,u) ds$? Then I am probably more in the setting of a classical ODE. I am just thinking what I would need for $k$ to apply Cauchy-Peano. Maybe $k(s,\cdot) \in \text{Lip}(\mathbb{R})$ and $k(\cdot,u) \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$?