# How to do this improper integrals??

Tags: improper-integrals

I'm trying to solve improper integrals but some patterns i can't do anything...
This question is patterns of them. please help to to solve this question

It's okay that helping just one of them. I really need somebody's help...

questions is "State whether the sequence converges as $n\to\infty$; if it does, find the limit."

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using, for example, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429769/is-an-integral-always-continuous) question we can see that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-1/n}^{1/n}(\sin{(x^2)}-\cos{(2x)})\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^0(\sin{(x^2)}-\cos{(2x)})\mathrm{d}x=0$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-1+1/n}^{1-1/n}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\int_{-1}^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\pi$$