# Showing that the image of an integral operator is continuous on a compact interval

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification, continuity, alternative-proof

There's already a proof for the following result on [Showing that a Volterra operator is well-defined.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4588110/showing-that-a-volterra-operator-is-well-defined) However I want to ask if my alternative proof is valid.

**Exercise:** Let $T : C[0,1] \rightarrow C[0,1]$ be defined as $Tf(x) = \int_0^xf(t)dt$. Show that $Tf$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.

**Attempt**: Take $f \in C[0,1]$. Since $f$ is continuous on a compact interval, then it has an upper-bound $M > 0$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ on $[0,1]$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Make $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{M} > 0$. Then, if $|x-y| < \delta$, it follows that \begin{align*}
  |Tf(x)-Tf(y)| & = \left|\int_y^xf(t)dt\right|\\
  & \leq \left|\int_y^x|f(t)|dt\right|\\
  & \leq M\left|\int_y^xdt\right|\\
  & \leq M|x-y|\\
  & < M\delta = \epsilon.
 \end{align*}

Comment: Why do you use ||•|| sometimes but |•| other times? Also, should your $(x - y)$ be $|x-y|$?

Comment: @JasonZimba Indeed, I should've used $|\cdot|$ all the time and $(x-y)$ should be $|x-y|$. I've corrected both mistakes. Thank you!

Comment: @JasonZimba If $M = 0$ I can just pick a new $M* > 0$ and it still is an upper bound for $f$? I am not picking the smaller M but instead, picking some positive M that we know it exists

Comment: Once you have $|Tf(x)-Tf(y)| \leq M|x-y|$ , it is more usual to apply the Squeeze Theorem. (As here for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429769/is-an-integral-always-continuous).  That makes it unnecessary to define a $\delta$. But your approach looks right to me also.

Comment: @JasonZimba Thank you very much!

Comment: Should you also include a preliminary observation that $Tf$ exists? (Because a continuous function on a compact interval is Riemann integrable.)